# Groovy Split html with tag and create a list

Tags: regex, groovy, html-parsing

I am working with groovy code to split string into array. I have following string

```
string html = "<html><body><b>I like subway at\n\n</b>I like subway at\n\n";
```

How can I get a list like

```
List splitList = ['<html>','<body>','<b>','I like subway at\n\n','</b>','I like subway at\n\n']
```

I am using following regex refered from stackoverflow-

```
List splittedList = html.split('(<\\/?\\w+(?:(?:\\s+\\w+(?:\\s*=\\s*(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^\'">\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)\\/?>)')
```

This does not work for groovy. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: As made astonishingly clear by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1269732), you might want to try using an [XML parser](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html) instead.

Comment: Since input string is not a valid HTML it restricts me to use any XML parser. Input data for my application will be part of the HTML file. Hence need to go with regex route. Do you know any parser which can help me to achieve this?

Comment: Ah right, I didn't notice the tags weren't closing. And I guess you have no way of getting a properly shaped XML string? Anyway, if your example is complete and the string you receive never contains tag attributes (like, always `<something>` and never `<something attr="anystring">), it could be safely sorted out. Otherwise it'd be likely to fail at some point. And no, sorry, I don't know of any parser that would handle invalid XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little convoluted, but I think it gets you most of the way there without regex:

```
html = """<html><body><b>I like subway at\n\n</b>I like subway at\n\n"""
new_html= html.replace('<','@<').replace('>','>@').replace('@@','@')
print(new_html.split('@')))
```

Output:

```
['', '<html>', '<body>', '<b>', 'I like subway at\n\n', '</b>', 'I like subway at\n\n']
```